# Changing Kendo options for chart after initialization

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am looking to change the options of a Kendo chart after the initial load and I am not sure exactly how to do this.

A simple example of what I am trying to do is as follows.  Let's say we have an object literal with all of our options in it.  I will use the `categoryAxis` option provided by Kendo as an example:

```
var myKendoOptions = {
    categoryAxis: {
        categories: [5, 6]
    }
}
```

Pretty straight forward right?  You can pass these options to your chart and they will work.

However, I can't seem to find any documentation on being able to change those values in the `categories` object if I want to do it at a later time after the chart has loaded.

I have seen `Kendo.datasource` but I am not sure this is what I want.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This code should work for you:

```
$("#chart").data("kendoChart").options.categoryAxis = { categories: [7, 8] }
$("#chart").data("kendoChart").redraw();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I don´t know if this work, but you can give a try

```
$("#myChart").kendoChart().options...;

$("#myChart").data("kendoChart").refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is the **setOptions** method

eg $('#chart').setOptions({...})

Which then redraws or refreshes.